# @font-face doesn't work in play-framework

Tags: css, playframework, font-face

In my CSS, I have:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: 'myFont';
src: url("fonts/bluepss.ttf");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

button {
font-family: myFont;
font-size: 40px;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #BDAEC6;
```

}

The bluepss.ttf file is stored in public/fonts/ folder. Any ideas why the font's not showing up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you convert your font to font-face or you just copy/paste it to your project ? (since i don't see the woff, eot, svg files )

Comment: Copy and paste. Am i supposed to do some converting?

Comment: Yes. You should use "http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator" and convert your font to font-face so different browsers can support it. Look here how it should look: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried and it's still not working. Is it because play can't find my files?

Comment: Try "/assets/fonts/bluepss.ttf" in your src: url("...");

Comment: Hey, thanks so much @cYn. I didn't use /assets/ but I used /public/ and it worked. I just realized that in the route file I had `GET     /public/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`. So instead of assets, i put public, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I was of help in a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @cYn, I found the answer. 
I realized that in the route file I had

`GET /public/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

So instead of assets, i put public, and it worked:
`/assets/fonts/bluepss.ttf`